# What to do if reference is a variable in Pine Script V4?

Tags: pine-script

When reading a previous candle's conditions we use [x]...
But how do you call on a previous condition with an unknown [x] location.
Sorry I'm new to scripting.

For example, I want my script to detect whether the current condition is greater than the previous one. Not a specific number of bars back, just "previously" or "most recently".

I don't want to print a "LONG" signal if the previous signal was "LONG"... But I don't know how many bars back the previous "LONG" signal was because that is a variable distance.

printlong = shortsignal[most recently?] lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generally use `valuewhen()` to obtain values you can use for comparison. For example :

```
long_val0 = valuewhen(long_signal, val, 0) // the most recent value of val when long_signal occurred.
long_val1 = valuewhen(long_signal, val, 1) // the second most recent value of val

short_val0 = valuewhen(short_signal, val, 0)
short_val1 = valuewhen(short_signal, val, 1)

long_index0 = valuewhen(long_signal, bar_index, 0)
long_index1 = valuewhen(long_signal, bar_index, 1)
    
short_index0 = valuewhen(short_signal, bar_index, 0)
short_index1 = valuewhen(short_signal, bar_index, 1)
```

Then you can use some logic test to determine most recent signal and their values. So for example if you just want to negate reentering a long if the previous signal was also a long.

This will return true if the previous signal was a `short_signal` and the current bar is a `long_signal`. We don't use `long_index0` here as it would return the `bar_index` of the current bar as it is the most recent `long_signal`

```
if long_signal and long_index1 < short_index0 
    // enter a new long
```

If you wanted to do something conditional, say only enter a consecutive long if a variable is higher than it was at the time of the last long_signal

```
if long_signal
    if long_index1 > short_index0 // If true, this would tell us if the last prior signal was long ( two consecutive long signals, current bar and previous signal)
        if long_val0 > long_val1 // current val is higher than the last
            // Do something like : still enter another long, otherwise if val is lower don't enter a long
    else // in the case that short_index0 > long_index1 (the prior signal was short)
        // Enter new long
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!
Stupid question probably, what is "val"?

Comment: Just a placeholder variable name for whatever you're using to create the long condition. You asked about if your current condition was greater than the last.

Comment: Right, thank you! Sorry, new to this, easily confused. Haha XD